# Basic function with 2 variables not working in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, function

I made a super basic function as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Function Canyou(A As Double, B As Double) As Double
    Canyou = A + B
End Function
```

The function is in a module in the worksheet where I want to use it. I then went into the worksheet and typed:
= Canyou(2,3)
And I get a value error. I tried instead to select cells with numbers in them like:
= Canyou (A1, B2)
and that didn't work at all.

Background info: I am working with a German version of Excel. But I also tried changing the commas to semicolon etc and none of this works (commas work in other places just fine).

Any ideas?

Thanks,
FHB[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0G3Y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In Germany, you should use German separators. Thus function should be written like this in Excel:

```
=Canyou(12;2)
```

Or like this, if you want to give floating point value as first argument -
`=Canyou(12,2;2)`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The function works for me having comma as list separator.

In case you are not sure of the separator settings on your PC, check in windows.
Region and Language / Additional settings/ List separator.

Kr,

W

Answer (score 0):

Functions have to be in standard modules not worksheet modules if you wish to use them on the spreadsheet. You should also declare them as Public